# Split an NSString into an array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

How can I split the string `@"Hello"` to either:

- a C array of `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`

or:

- an Objective-C array of `@[@"H", @"e", @"l", @"l", @"o"]`

Comment: Take a look at [NSString get -characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886882/nsstring-get-characters) and [How to get a single NSString character from an NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836670/how-to-get-a-single-nsstring-character-from-an-nsstring) post.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're satisfied with a C array of `char`s, try:

```
const char *array = [@"Hello" UTF8String];
```

If you need an NSArray, try:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *str = @"Hello";
for (int i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
    NSString *ch = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [array addObject:ch];
}
```

And `array` will contain each character as an element of it.

Comment: is there a command to replace a letter in array? like [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0] hah, something like that? if i want to replace something in array index?

Comment: @H2CO3 instead of using substring with a range of 1, just use `-characterAtIndex:`.

Comment: And how do you add the non-object `char' to the array?

Comment: Loop your `const char *array` with: `for (int i; i < sizeof(array); i++) { doSomethingWith(array[i]); }`

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
- (void) testCode
{
    NSString *tempDigit = @"12345abcd" ;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [tempDigit enumerateSubstringsInRange:[tempDigit rangeOfString:tempDigit]
                                  options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                               usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
            [tempArray addObject:substring] ;
        }] ;

    NSLog(@"tempArray = %@" , tempArray);
}
```

Comment: Upvote for being UTF8 aware and keeping multi byte characters (emoji, åccented characters) together.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index` to access the string characters at each index.

So,

```
NSString* stringie = @"astring";
NSUInteger length = [stringie length];
unichar stringieChars[length];
for( unsigned int pos = 0 ; pos < length ; ++pos )
{
    stringieChars[pos] = [stringie characterAtIndex:pos];
}
// replace the 4th element of stringieChars with an 'a' character
stringieChars[3] = 'a';
// print the modified array you produced from the NSString*
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithCharacters:stringieChars length:length]);
```

Comment: is there a command to replace a letter in array? like [array replaceObjectAtIndex:0] hah, something like that? if i want to replace something in array index?

Comment: Now you've got a basic C array that you can make changes to index by index.  I changed my answer to reflect your added question.

Answer (score 0):

A user529758 mentions, split your string - the C way - like:

```
const char *array = [@"Hello" UTF8String];
```

But then loop it using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
  doSomethingWithCharacter(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: remember that `const char *array` from strings may end with the NUL character for terminating strings `'\0'`, so your size may be 1 larger than the amount of readable characters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart