# How to capture a single character from NSString using substringToIndex

Tags: objective-c, substring, nsstring

I have a NSString that has two characters.

The NSSring looks something like this

> FW

I use this code to capture the first character:

```
NSString *firstStateString = [totInstStateString substringToIndex:1];
```

This piece of code returns F, I would like to know how to return the second character to its own string using substringToIndex.

Comment: Well with `substringToIndex` will be very difficult since it will always start at position 0.

Answer (score 5):

Use substringWithRange:

For Example :

> [@"fw" substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];

will get you @"w"

have a look at the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code .. My be helpful in your case.

```
NSString *myString = @"FFNNF";

for(int i = 0; i < [myString length]; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@", [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)])
}
```

Also check This Question.

[How to get a single NSString character from an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836670/how-to-get-a-single-nsstring-character-from-an-nsstring/18690447#18690447)

Comment: This will output: `F`, `FF`, `FFN` and `FFNN`. Ask you can see it will always start at index 0, but the question whas how the get the second letter.

Comment: @rckoenes -- Thanks you sir, for inform me.. i changed my answer check it now.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is:

```
NSString *lastStateString = [totInstStateString substringFromIndex:1];
```

This will get the last character of a two-character string. You might want to do some bounds checking somewhere in there.